# Pymssql Install Error

Tags: python, windows, windows-server-2012-r2, freetds, pymssql

I'm trying to install FreeTDS using binaries from [here](https://github.com/ramiro/freetds/releases), on Windows, but I can't figure out how to install binary files; a google search turned up nothing relevant. I'm installing so that the Python module Pymssql can be imported and used.

I'm getting the same error as in this post: https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/372

Comment: http://pymssql.org/en/latest/freetds.html#windows here it states: If applicable, add the directories that hold the above DLLs to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: @AndreaConte I did that, and the error changed to me needing to install Visual C++ but after I did that it went back to what it is now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate the specifics of your Python install: distribution (where did you get your Python installer?), exact Python version, 64-bit or 32-bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem by moving all the `.h` files from the FreeTDS and OpenSSL files I downloaded into where all the other .h files were in `C:\Users\KAllen\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\include`, and put all the `.dll` files with the others in `C:\Users\KAllen\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\bin`

Answer (score 3):

You can download the Windows binaries here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/freetdswindows/

There is an executable installer in the ZIP file you download; install away. It should install the necessary binaries you need. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

1. Download and install pymssql wheels from here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql

Download and then `pip install %userprofile%\downloads\pymssql-2.1.2-cp**-cp**m-win??.whl`

2. `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/prometeia pymssql`
3. WinPython may soon include pymssql by default:

https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/307